# this.platform.is("mobile") returning true for browser

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am running a ionic project on browser

**script**

```
"browser": "ionic-app-scripts serve --sourceMap source-map --iscordovaserve --wwwDir platforms/browser/www/ --buildDir platforms/browser/www/build"
```

and running `npm run browser`

I am trying this piece of code in `app.component.ts`

```
if (this.platform.is('ios') || this.platform.is('android') || this.platform.is('mobile'))
//execute certain function only on mobile
```

**Problem**

`this.platform.is('mobile')` and `this.platform.is('android')` is returning `true` to me in case of browser which is weird behaviour.

So , how to obtain the condition so that on browser i want to disable certain feature and why is the above code not working as expected.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this app gonna be used in the browser too? Or just in the mobile devices?

Comment: Just the mobile devices. But it throws error when we test in the browser.So just want to skip that on browser while development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches i got.

**As suggested By Sergey**

```
let isWebApp = this.platform.url().startsWith('http');
```

**Found on the Ionic Forum**

```
!document.URL.startsWith('http');
```

These are mainly used for development as development process is faster is in browser as changes are reflected instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think you need this but you can use:

```
 if(this.platform.is('core') || this.platform.is('mobileweb')) {
        // In Browser
      } else {
        // In Mobile
      }
```

Comment: this was returning false in case of browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other way to detect whether your app is web app or a cordova hybrid app:

```
let isWebApp = this.platform.url().startsWith('http');
```

In cordova (on device basically) depending on platform the app's "url" will start from "file://" or other but not http.

Answer (score 0):

If you Enabled **Toggle device toolbar** from browser, It'll return mobile.
and if it is disabled then return desktop.
[image]

You can see it'll return desktop by disabling **Toggle device toolbar** from the browser:
[image]

You have to refresh(**f5**) the page after changing the state of **Toggle device toolbar** or it'll not work, because it was cached.

Comment: This is not relevant, it's returning 'mobile' in any case, with devtools on or off, and device toolbar on or off